# Creating One-To-Many mapping where Many can be different object types

Tags: php, mysql, orm, doctrine, doctrine-orm

I am exploring the feasibility of retrofitting an existing database to using Doctrine.

I have three tables, a ***StockRequest, SalesOrder, WorkOrder***. ***StockRequest*** has fields *Type* and *TypeNo*. Type is used to decide whether it has a relationship with a Sales Order or a WorkOrder, and TypeNo is the key of the ***SalesOrder/WorkOrder***.

What is the recommended method to maintain this relationship?

Reading the doctrine documentation, it mentions a repository class, which I could use to conditionally fetch based on Type, maintaining only one StockRequest Entity.

The other possibility would be to Subclass the StockRequest class so that I have ***SalesOrderStockRequests*** and ***WorkOrderStockRequests***.

Comment: I have this exact same question - how did you get on?

Comment: I decided on subclassing. You can stick all the common logic inside the abstract class, and just override the fields and methods that are different. I think this is the way to go, otherwise we'd have to do some nasty coupling with the Entity manager.

Answer (score 0):

I would make it with inheritanceand relationship, example:

```
abstract class AbstractOrder {
 common fields
}

class SalesOrder extends AbstractOrder {

}

class WorkOrder extends AbstractOrder {

}
```

then

```
class StockRequest {
   relationship pointing to AbstractOrder
}
```

and when u getOrder() { return $this->order; }
Doctrine can return u instanceof either SalesOrder or WorkOrder